# Outlook VBA unzip attachment and save to folder

Tags: vba, outlook

I receive system generated e-mails from an ERP system which contain .zip files, inside the zip file is an excel file which contains data I'd like to import into a dashboard i have made.

At the moment i have this code which successfully saves the .zip attachment into the folder when i receive the email:

```
Sub saveAttachment2(Item As Outlook.MailItem)
Dim selItems            As Selection
Dim objItem             As Object
Dim iCount               As Integer
Dim atmts                 As Attachments
Dim oAttachment As Attachment
Dim sSaveFolder As String

Set selItems = ActiveExplorer.Selection
sSaveFolder = "C:\Users\212357980\Documents\Accounts Coordination\Oracle    Exports\"
For Each objItem In selItems
    Set atmts = objItem.Attachments
    For Each oAttachment In atmts
        oAttachment.SaveAsFile sSaveFolder & "\Service Requests.zip"
    Next
Next
End Sub
```

Now i would like it to unzip the file before it saves in the location, this is what i have so far:

```
Sub Unzip2()

    Dim ns As NameSpace             'variables for the main functionality
    Dim Inbox As MAPIFolder
    Dim SubFolder As MAPIFolder
    Dim Atchmt As Attachment
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim msg As Outlook.MailItem

    Dim FSO As Object               'variables for unzipping
    Dim oApp As Object
    Dim FileNameFolder As Variant
    Set ns = GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set Inbox = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set SubFolder = Inbox.Folders("Sales Orders")

   For Each msg In SubFolder.Items
            For Each Atchmt In msg.Attachments
                    If (Right(Atchmt.FileName, 3) = "zip") Then

                                    FileNameFolder = "C:\Users\212357980\Documents\Accounts Coordination\Oracle Exports\"
                                    Set oApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
                                    With oApp
                                        .NameSpace(FileNameFolder).CopyHere
                                        .NameSpace(Atchmt.FileName).Items
                                    End With

                                    On Error Resume Next
                                    Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
                                FSO.deletefolder Environ("Temp") & "\Temporary Directory*", True
                    End If
             Next
    Next
End Sub
```

I get the error "Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment" on the two lines after the with.

Any help you can provide would be great!

Comment: You will need to save the zip to a temp folder and extract it from there: pretty sure you cannot do this without saving it first.

Comment: Those two lines inside your `With oApp` block should be on one line.

Answer (score 0):

look: 
NameSpace(Atchmt.FileName).Items
suggests there are several items. You are trying to collect them all in one item.

Try
for n = 1 to (number of attachments)
NameSpace(Atchmt.FileName).Items(n)
.. etc ...

Comment: PeakPeak, I'm getting the error on the line above also, i tried to dim n as integer and then set n = 1 and added an (n) after items like you suggested but this did not work, do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: You are the expert regarding your case and you know everything about it. Please do not assume that other people also have the full knowledge of it.
Please be more specific and detailed: What do you want to acheive? What is working already? What is not working like it should? What are the error messages?

Comment: Hi peak peak, I believe if you read the original post you'll see I have answered all of that

Comment: "Did not work" is not helpful to the people here who are trying to help you.

Comment: Read the original post not my reply to you, I state what already works and what I've tried so far, I've also stated what I'm trying to achieve. And I've included the error message. When I tried what you said I put "dim n as integer" at the top, then I put "set n = 1", at the end of the code which ends .item I put "(n)" as you suggested, the error code in this instance was on the "set n = 1" line and it said that n needed to be an object.